# dnsmasq - different tftp-root for each macaddress

Tags: linux, debian, dnsmasq

Is it possible to address different tftp-roots inside dnsmasq.conf?

Something like:
IF MAC=19-4B-90-DA-1C-C3
THEN tftp-root=/tftpbootAB

IF MAC=19-4B-90-DE-1C-B6
THEN tftp-root=/tftpbootCD

I couldn't find this in the manual.

I only found something like:
dhcp-match=set:bios,option:client-arch,0
dhcp-boot=tag:efi-x86_64,"efi64/syslinux.efi"

But not for the line with tftp-root

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was also looking for this and have found the solution in `man dnsmasq`. There is an option:

> --tftp-unique-root[=ip|mac]
>   Add the IP or hardware address of the TFTP client as a path component on the end of the TFTP-root. Only valid if a tftp-root is set and the directory exists.  Defaults to adding IP address (in standard dotted-quad  format). For instance,  if  tftp-root  is  "/tftp"  and  client  1.2.3.4 requests file "myfile" then the effective path will be "/tftp/1.2.3.4/myfile" if /tftp/1.2.3.4 exists or /tftp/myfile otherwise.  When "=mac" is specified it will append the MAC address instead, using lowercase zero padded digits separated by dashes, e.g.: 01-02-03-04-aa-bb Note that resolving MAC addresses is only possible if the client is in the local network or obtained a DHCP lease from us.

The snippet in `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` then looks like this (example):

```
enable-tftp
tftp-root=/tftpboot
tftp-unique-root=mac
pxe-service=0,"Raspberry Pi Boot"
```

Then create the directories:

```
~$ sudo mkdir -p /tftpboot/19-4b-90-da-1c-c3
~$ sudo mkdir -p /tftpboot/19-4b-90-de-1c-b6
```

and put the boot files you want for the specific device (mac address) into its subdirectory.